# Using a variable inside and outside of a JQuery function.

Tags: jquery, variables

I have 2 JQuery Functions:

```
    $('.satnav').change(function() {
        $('#satnavadd').show();
        var price = "<?php echo $finalprice; ?>";
        //alert(price);
        var numofdays = "<?php echo $length->days; ?>";
        //alert(numofdays);
        var numberofsatnav = $(this).val();
        //alert(numberofsatnav);
        var satnavcost = Number(3) * Number(numofdays);
       //alert(satnavcost);
        var satnavtotal = Number(numberofsatnav) * Number(satnavcost);
        var newprice = Number(price) + Number(satnavtotal);
        $("input#satnavprice").val(satnavtotal);
        $("input#satnavnum").val(numberofsatnav);

    });


        $('.boostseat').change(function() {
            $('#boostseatadd').show();

            var price = "<?php echo number_format($finalprice, 2); ?>";
            //alert(price);
            var numberofboostseat = $(this).val();
            //alert(numberofboostseat);
            var numofdays = "<?php echo $length->days; ?>";
            //alert(numofdays);
            var boostcost = Number(3) * Number(numofdays);
            var boosttotal = Number(numberofboostseat) * Number(boostcost);
            var newprice = Number(price) + Number(boosttotal);
            $("input#hiddenboostprice").val(boosttotal);
            $("input#hiddenboostnum").val(numberofboostseat);

        });
```

As you can see they both calculate prices and then update HTML elements, however I would also like to add both the final totals together.

So for example:

```
var extrastotal = Number(boosttotal) + Number(satnavtotal);
```

However I cannot move the variable outside the function, or it will not work. Is there anyway to get around this somehow or would it involve writing another function with duplicate code for both?

Comment: Make a global variable, or use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) to store it directly in the appropriate DOM element(s).

Comment: You don't want to use global variable?

Comment: I'm new to JQuery sorry, I can turn a variable inside a function into a global variable?

Comment: It's not specific to jQuery, it's just an ordinary Javascript variable. Declare it at toplevel, or within the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Yeah i just dropped var and set it outside, sorry for the easiness of that :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a global variable outside of the functions and then have each do a += to add to the value.